# Selenium webdriver Not able to click on log out

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
```

I used above line of code to logout.Until yesterday it was working but today it is not.

I have used below xpath:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
```

It is still not working,
Later I found that I focus on logout option than it does the operation of logout.
Why is it so?
and why it was working yesterday but not today?

Comment: please check if your browser hasn't updated on its own..else you will loose compatibility with selenium version

Comment: It's no good saying things like 'yesterday' and 'not working', people need browser versions for Selenium issues, and specific errors.

Comment: seems like html code has been changed from yesterday, if you highlighting it and it works that mean it was not enable and as you said it is a drop down then if you click on drop down then only it should be enable so highlighting makes sense.

Comment: Please provide HTML code from DIV tag. So we can identify proper xpath

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue may be that your browser is loading cached page that has broken logout button . You need to give more strict Xpath and wait to make sure the whole page load

"/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li/div/ul/li[3]/a"

Make it strict something like -

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Button[text()='logout']")).click();

Comment: logout is not button.It is option under a dropdown menu

Comment: Just try to give it a exact and strict Xpath because they way you have written Xpath -If any element on the page do not load properly , it will fail. It is not a recommended way to give full hierarchy in xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log Out")).click();
```

**Or**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack trace might be very helpful to find a solution for you.
It could be, that

- the dropdown menu entry for log out needs short time to become **visible**? 
  Selenium acts like a user and can interacts with visible elements.

  - You could click on the dropdown use WebDriverWait.Until(..) to wait until it appears and use it

    or
  - Another way might be navigating directly to log out url.
- the link text has changed (blanks, capital letters ..)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```